# Visual studio 2019 no notifications

Tags: visual-studio

Visual studio 2019 will not show me notifications, like vs update or extension update available.  This started for no reason.  I do not want to do a regedit or any other kind of registry edit on my work pc.  Also, reinstalling vs19 is not an option.

The notification badges are in the bottom right.  But I stopped getting badges.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I went to Visual Studio Installer from start menu, and installed the new version, despite not getting a notification/badge to do so.  After ~10 days it started working again.